# Non-Continuous HTML Inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number input that needs to have a range from 1000 to some arbitrary maximum but also takes zero as a valid input. What's the best way to approach a non-continuous range of possible inputs?

A hack-y way to do it would perhaps be to set the range from zero the maximum and round anything from 1-999 up to 1000. Maybe there's a way to make it so that when you tick up from 0, it goes to 1000 and if you tick down from 1000 it jumps straight to 0.

I don't think having a 'zero' checkbox next to the input is a viable solution, the value needs to be handled by the input itself.

An additional requirement of the problem is that the value 0 should show the text 'none' instead of the number. My first approach would be to use an angular formatter but I'd love to know if there are easier solutions.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your requirements, a regular `input type=number` or `input type=range` won't work for you. You'd need a custom solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pattern` attribute on an input element.

```css
:valid { background: #cfc; }
:invalid { background: #fcc; }
```

```html
<input pattern='0|\d{4,}' required>
```

This pattern matches the zero character, as well as any number that is 4 digits or larger (so ≥ 1,000). I've also put the `required` attribute on, as you presumably want a value to be submitted. The CSS is for stylistic purposes so you can see what is acceptable and what isn't.

If you need a specific maximum (that is an even power of 10), then you can simply tack put that power in the second part of the regex. For any other number (say 2,000), that would get a bit trickier.

---

Edit: Here's a JS-only solution that involves manipulating the `min` attribute on a number input.

```css
:valid { background: #cfc; }
:invalid { background: #fcc; }
```

```html
<input
  type='number'
  oninput='setAttribute("min", value == 0 ? 0 : 1000)'
  min='0'
  max='86400000'
  required
>
```

Naturally if you're using this in many places, you should extract that away to a proper function that is bound is passed a parameter `this` (the input in question). All it does is check if the input is *exactly* zero, and changes the `min` value appropriately. If it's not zero, it has to be between 1000 and 86,400,000.

Comment: The regex idea is interesting, I hadn't considered using it for this. Perhaps a regex could be applied to a number input such that if I set my range from 0-86400000, it would flag everything from 1-999 as invalid?

Comment: @PaulMurray According to MDN, `input type='number'` does not support the `pattern` attribute, so that wouldn't work. You could naturally use JS for validation, if that's an option?

Comment: I think having the functionality of the number input is important -- most likely my approach will be to extend the range to 0 and then use java-script to automatically adjust the invalid numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your angular version, and there are both the tags `angular` and `angularjs`.

I assume you are using **Angular2+** (that is reffered as `angular`).

You can use the following HTML:

```html
<input  type="number" min="0" max="999999" [step]="step" placeholder="none" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="changeValue($event)">
```

And the code to handle it in your component:

```ts
public value: number;
public step = 1000;

public changeValue(newValue: number) {
    newValue = newValue || 0;

    if ((0 < newValue) && (newValue < 1000)) {
        if (newValue < this.value) {
            newValue = null;
        } else {
            newValue = 1000;
        }
    }

    newValue = newValue || null;        

    if ((!newValue) || (newValue != this.value)) {
        if ((!newValue) && (this.value === null)) {
            // to trigger changes
            newValue = undefined;
        }

        this.value = newValue;
        this.step = this.value ? 1 : 1000;
    }
}
```

You handle it in a function that changes the value based on the valid values.

The step is `1000` when there is no value and `1` when there is a value of `1000` or plus.

I'm doing in a way that the value is not `0`, and instead is `null`/`undefined`, so I can show the placeholder `none` instead of the value `0`.

Comment: Ah my mistake, using angular 1 actually

Comment: Ah, sorry then :S

Comment: @PaulMurray I haven't programmed in angular 1, but maybe you can reuse the logic though.